# Java Mail Issue with Session.getInstance

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

I am receiving the following exception when trying to use java mail;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:247)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSender.createSmtpSession(MailSender.java:67)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSender.sendSimpleMessage(MailSender.java:38)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSender.generateLostPasswordEmail(MailSender.java:79)
    at com.secondstory.mailsender.MailSenderTest.shouldReturnTrueWithCredentialsSet(MailSenderTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 30 more
```

After searching stack overflow extensively (maybe not extensively enough - lets see!) I have found that we need two jars inside our maven pom for this too work. The two dependancies I have are as follows;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Something has changed but I am not entirely sure what it is - as this worked previously. The code i have written where this element fails is as follows;

```
private static Session createSmtpSession() {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.host", "host");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    //props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

    return Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                            "username", "password");
                }
            });
}
```

Am I missing some config or should this work with the current setup that I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try adding this into Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As explained on the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), com.sun.mail:javax.mail is the entire implementation; it's what you need if you're running an application.  If you only need to compile your application (e.g., if you're going to deploy it elsewhere to run it), all you need is javax.mail:javax.mail-api.  You only need javax.activation if you're using an older JDK; it's included in newer JDKs.

Comment: Where can I get the "com.sun.mail:javax.mail" library? All I can find online is only the javax.mail-1.6.1 which is good only for compiling.

Comment: I found it, it's the javax.mail.jar that can be downloaded on this page: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use `javax.mail-api.jar`. That is the wrong library. JavaMail is a Java EE specification, the interfaces of that specification are published in that `javax.mail-api-1.6.1.jar`, which only works when compiling. It doesn't provide an implementation of the specification, so it doesn't work at runtime.

You need to use an implementation of the JavaMail specification at runtime. You can find the reference implementation on https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ (but there are others, for example Java EE application servers usually include one).

For `javax.mail-api.jar`, https://javaee.github.io/javamail/ says:

> The JavaMail API definitions only, suitable for compiling against; use
>   only with a Maven “provided” dependency scope

Specifically in your case you need either `javax.mail.jar` or `mailapi.jar` + the jars of the specific protocols you want to use. For example `mailapi.jar` + `smtp.jar` if you only need smtp(s) support.

With Maven, you can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```