# How do I resolve "Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger" on Android?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jakarta-mail

I import in gradle:

```
implementation  'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
```

Unfortunately, I still get an error that MailLogger can't be loaded.

```
2019-07-22 17:54:29.444 5088-5162/com.ra.ra_e_akte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-18
    Process: com.ra.ra_e_akte, PID: 5088
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;
        at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:226)
        at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
        at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:264)
```

I found another question on a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807472/java-mail-issue-with-session-getinstance) but from the answer to that question, it seems they target a different buildprocess in Java land that doesn't use gradle.
How do I get the libraries imported into gradle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51000554/115145 -- "The problem is that you are trying to use javax.mail-api.jar. That is the wrong library."

Comment: Follow the instructions on the [JavaMail web site](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by using [Android specific libraries](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) (the javax-package needs dependencies that don't exist in Android):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly the same problem despite using the latest version of javax.mail:javax.mail-api today (2023-09-11). Your solution works perfectly.